# How to make user log, using java EE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, logging

I have program like this, i have server and i have website to control and communicate to server through web service. And website doesn't store anything and doesn't have Database, all proses send to server (login, view member, create member , etc).

[image]

My question is how to make user log , so i know what user / admin / whoever doing after logon, did he view member or anything what he do.

i know, we can put on every button and then we store what ever he doing in temporary database and send to server after the session is destroyed. But if i do that i must open all code and put 1 or  more line in the button. I want to avoid that, so there is a way i know what user/admin do after he login beside put code in every button???

Programming language : Java EE

I using NetBeans IDE 6.9 (Build 201006101454)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

It may be hard to log every UI event, but it's quite easy to trace every web service calls : just create a logging aspect :

http://thoughtforge.net/2010/02/16/creating-a-logging-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try ObjectLogger : https://github.com/yeecode/ObjectLogger

A powerful and easy-to-use object log system, supports writing and querying of object attribute changes.